# Visual Studio not Copying Directory of Linked Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies

A common practice when staging unmanaged libraries or resources is to add those resources as links to the project and set them to copy to the output directory.

As of Visual Studio 2013, this is handled quite well and even if they are referenced Library `Foo` which is then consumed by Application `Bar`, they will end up in `Bar`'s output directory.

The same doesn't appear to be true for directories of files though.

[image: Referenced file in library]

In this case, my application appears to only copy this directory of files to the output directory on **rebuild** only. Then inevitably I'll do a couple **build** actions and I'll notice the `Libs` directory is empty again. Then do a **Rebuild** and `cef.pak` is back.

My solution to this was to employ a *Build Step* to copy the `Libs` directory manually to the output directory. Though I cannot find the proper macro to generically express that even though this build step is part of `Foo`, I want the files copied to the `Bar`'s (e.g. *StartUp Project* in VS terms) output directory.

**Update**

Thank you everyone for the great answers and testing this. I should clarify that I still see this issue when there is an extra level of library in between. That is to say Application `Bar` referencing library `Foo` which references library `Other` which is the one w/ these linked files. In that case, when `Other`'s linked files are set to copy to output directory, they seem to only make it on rebuilds. My solution to this is less than ideal which is to have `Foo` reference `Other` directly.

Comment: I have faced this issue (read my answer) if you want more solutions add a comment and I'll offer you. please submit bug to Microsoft and maybe they will fix it (last time they renounce...)

Comment: accept an answer if it helped you, or the bounty is going to be wasted (you'll still loose it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless you rebuild/clean solution, VS does remove files from output folder.
so i believe you forgot to say that your program(or third party) does so.

First: [this](https://github.com/OldFox1/BuildWillNotCopy) is an example for similar/exact bug.
download the solution and do the following steps:

1. rebuild the solution
2. open the output folder of Bar
3. the file cef.pak will be exist in Libs
4. press F5 -> execute Bar -> everything alright
5. execute again with F5 -> you will receive an file not found exception
6. if you repeat steps 1-5 you will receive the same behavior

   - The issue exist only if there is no changes in Bar and something(the exe / other process/etc) has deleted the file.

Second: I've already faced this issue.
when one of my team member reported this issue, then the answer he received was a kind of "it's not a bug it's a feature"....

As i know, there is no "magic button" to solve for this problem.

But there are several workarounds:

1. (as you did) adding pre/post build events. I recommend you to do this in new build configuration.
2. change the build output folder of Foo to Bar output folder.
3. add in your code a path replacement with if debug:

   ```
   #if DEBUG
               cefFilePath = <build output of foo>
   #endif
   ```
4. put the file as embedded resource then extract it.
5. create an extension\external program to deal with this problem. each project the file keep the information about those file:

> ```
>   <ItemGroup>
>     <None Include="Libs\cef.pak">
>       <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
>     </None>
>   </ItemGroup>
> ```

the application/plugin will do the job for you.

I can offer more solutions/workarounds, but I believe that you did the right thing -> build event.

**edit:**

I updated my example in the link. now the solution contains 3 workarounds example.

Answer (score 2):

Tried doing same with VS2013. It worked quite well, everytime I change something in Bar's File, Run Foo (Startup Project), the latest file is copied there. I am just writing steps I followed, may be I am missing something to replicate or you missed a step. Please have a look:

1. Create two Projects Foo and Bar
2. Created a directory Libs in Bar
3. Added a text file "TextFile1.txt" in Libs
4. **Right Click -> Properties of the file -> Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always**
5. Added reference of Bar from Foo Project
6. Started reading the TextFile's text from Foo's Main method. Reading file from Bin\Debug\Libs directory.
7. Every time I press F5 I see the latest file get copied there.

Comment: Your answer won't work, I already faced this problem. in my answer, i put a link to solution that demonstrate this problem. on rebuild the file was copy to output folder of Bar, so "Copy to Output Directory" is: "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer". "Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always" will copy the file only to output folder of Foo, and then MsBuild copy the file to Bar's folder. in this case MsBuild didn't do the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Edit "Foo.csproj" (make sure the project is closed in VS) and add this add the bottom, in place of a commented out example that is already there in every new project file (use your own paths):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Libs\cef.pak;Libs\file2.ext" DestinationFolder="..\..\Bar Solution\Bar Project\output" SkipUnchangedFiles="True" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
</Target>
```

Edit "Bar.csproj" as well, just in case changing those files doesn't trigger Foo build:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\Foo Solution\Foo Project\Libs\cef.pak;..\..\Foo Solution\Foo Project\Libs\file2.ext" DestinationFolder="output" SkipUnchangedFiles="True" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" />
</Target>
```